# Use alt.Chart() with data from a google drive url link

Tags: python, json, google-colaboratory, altair

I am plotting with altair in google colab. I have hit the 'max row' warning: https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/faq.html#maxrowserror-how-can-i-plot-large-datasets .

this is the head fo my dataset: [df.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9JB5.png)

So now i am trying to pass data by URL, liking to my googleDrive:
firstly i exported the file to my drive:

```py
"change directory and export whole csv "
os.chdir(Directory.table_dir)
one.to_json('one.json', orient='records')
```

Then i tried to use the URLData method: https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.UrlData.html#altair.UrlData

```py
os.chdir(Directory.table_dir)
#checking if i can read the file to a pandas dataframe
df=pd.read_json('one.json', orient='records')

source=alt.UrlData('content/gdrive/My Drive/SCTFT/Tables/one.json')


chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x='VG:Q',
    y='absID:Q',
    color='file:N',
)
chart
```

I also tried:

```py
source='content/gdrive/My Drive/SCTFT/Tables/one.json'
```

Plotting from matplotlib using df works.

But from altair i get:
[altair plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3E5V.png)

I get no error messages.
Should i change the way i'm exporting the file? or how i link it with the URL?

EDITING WITH NEW INFORMATION

I ran the code from https://colab.research.google.com/github/altair-viz/altair_data_server/blob/master/AltairDataServer.ipynb
: [pip install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/974V9.png)
[first graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PPa9.png)

it worked all the way until:

[Altair data server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqxpw.png)

this was justme runnign the notebook without making any changes, so there must be an issue with how my colab is set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL data you pass to the chart has to be visible to the frontend via an HTTP request, and `content/gdrive/My Drive/SCTFT/Tables/one.json` does not look like a valid URL.

Since your data is on Google drive and is not available via an HTTP URL, I would suggest [disabling the maximum rows check](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/faq.html#disabling-maxrows) and passing the dataframe to the chart directly:

```
alt.data_transformers.enable(max_rows=None)

alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='VG:Q',
    y='absID:Q',
    color='file:N',
)
```

Comment: ok, but  i am going to put in my notebook 6-7 interactive graphs, like the multi-panel Scatter plot, each handling about 11.000 rows of data. So i am concerned about the performance suffering. Will it be fine, or is there a place to upload my data in a way that it can be linked?

Comment: If you're worried about embedding data in the notebook, you can use the [altair data server](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/faq.html#local-data-server) approach.

Comment: i had tried that, maybe i'm not passing the data correctly. i did: !pip install altair_data_server and then ran:   alt.data_transformers.enable('data_server') ----   df=pd.read_json('one.json', orient='records') ----    chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='VG:Q',
    y='absID:Q',
)----  chart -----      and got a blank graph

Comment: The data server works in Colab – the blank graph is likely a problem with your data or your code (hard to tell without more information).

Comment: i just followed the link you gave me until a google colab: https://colab.research.google.com/github/altair-viz/altair_data_server/blob/master/AltairDataServer.ipynb  and just ran it with ctrl-f9 and the graph is also blank. I'm going to add the detail to my question so it's easier to see

Comment: I just executed the notebook and it works for me. Do you have an ad-blocker turned on? Sometimes that can prevent the javascript from accessing URL-based data. See https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#plot-displays-but-the-content-is-empty

Comment: Yes, that was it!! i downloaded chrome instead of Firefox and ran it without any adblocks. Thanks!